# Can MLFlow log new metrics in a terminated run?

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, mlflow

I would like to use MLFlow (with Python) to log time series with time interval equal to 1 day.
My idea would be to create a new run with a certain ID and to use function `log_metric` every day (say, with a cron job) with a new value. Once my run is terminated, can I "reopen" it and log a new metric ?
What I have in mind is:

```py
# Day 1
import mlflow

tracking_uri = "my_uri"
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(tracking_uri)
xp_id = 0
mlflow.start_run(run_name="test", experiment_id=xp_id)
mlflow.log_metric("test_metric", 1)
mlflow.end_run()
```

And the following days:

```py
import mlflow

def log_daily_metric(daily_value_metric):
  tracking_uri = "my_uri"
  mlflow.set_tracking_uri(tracking_uri)
  xp_id = 0
  mlflow.restart_run(run_name="test", experiment_id=xp_id)  # /!\ function mlflow.restart does not exist
  mlflow.log_metric("test_metric", daily_value_metric)
  mlflow.end_run()
```

so that run `"test"` would have new metrics logged every day.

Any idea to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be:

```py
# day 1

import mlflow

tracking_uri = "my_uri"
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(tracking_uri)
xp_id = 0

client = MlflowClient()
run = client.create_run(experiment_id=xp_id)
print(run.info.run_id)  # gives you the run ID of your experiment. Example: "df85f660dca47d21b41454342cd3a7cb". Let's save this id somewhere...
```

Then,

```py
import mlflow

def log_daily_metric(daily_value_metric: float, day: int):
  tracking_uri = "my_uri"
  mlflow.set_tracking_uri(tracking_uri)
  xp_id = 0
  client = MlflowClient()
  run_id = "df85f660dca47d21b41454342cd3a7cb"
  client.log_metric(run_id=run_id, key="test_metric", value=daily_value_metric, step=day)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but here is what I found, with mlflow 1.28.

**Step 1.**: find the `run_id`.

```py
xp_id = mlflow.get_experiment_by_name('your_experiment')._experiment_id
run_id = mlflow.search_runs(xp, output_format="list")[0].info.run_id
```

Note, by default, mlflow.search_runs lists runs from newest to oldest.

**Step 2.**:

Re-activate run by `run_id`, by passing it to `mlflow.start_run`.

```py
mlflow.set_experiment('your_experiment')
with mlflow.start_run(run_id):
    mlflow.log_param('new', 'param!')
```